# "Don't feature what you are putting down." Meaning

Tags: meaning, word-usage

This is the next question about the [same song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pb3R3FoYsmc) I asked short time ago.

1:37～ She sings "I don't feature what you are putting down."

I took "putting down" as "something written".

So would that mean, "I don't appreciate (or not be impressed) by what you wrote"?

And does she have some dialectic tone?

I am sorry I didn't know this is [Mandy Moore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandy_Moore)'s song. And here is the lyric of the song. ( I raised the part of the lyric so that people may be able to see much more clearly. )

> Stupid Cupid, you're a real mean guy
>   I'd like to clip your wings so you can't fly
>   I am in love and it's a crying shame
>   And I know that you're the one to blame
>   Hey hey, set me free
>   Stupid Cupid, stop picking on me
>   Can't do my homework and I can't think straight
>   I meet him every morning at 'bout half past eight
>   I'm acting like a lovesick fool
>   You've even got me carrying his books to school
>   Hey hey, set me free
>   Stupid Cupid, stop picking on me
>   You mixed me up for good
>   Right from the very start
>   Hey, go play Robin Hood
>   With somebody else's heart
>   You got me jumping like a crazy clown
>   **And I don't feature what your puttin' down**
>   Since I kissed his loving lips of wine
>   The thing that bothers me is that I like it fine
>   Hey hey, set me free
>   Stupid Cupid, stop picking on me
>   You got me jumping like a crazy clown
>   **And I don't feature what your puttin' down**
>   Since I kissed his loving lips of wine
>   The thing that bothers me is that I like it fine
>   Hey hey, set me free
>   Stupid Cupid, stop picking on me
>   Hey hey, set me free
>   Stupid Cupid, stop picking on me

Comment: Can you link to a lyrics page rather than the video? I'd rather not go to Youtube to see what the full lyrics of the song are and you don't even state the title in your question. Please include the necessary details for us!

Comment: @Catija Lyrics are in the video description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Putting down" in this case is referring to how somebody is acting. But it's uncommon to use it that way in everyday speech. It's a bit strange to use the word "Feature" in this manner as well. This lyric could be simply interpreted as *I don't like how you're acting*.

But be careful in using "Putting down" as it can have many different meanings depending on context. You're correct to think it means *something written*.

> Let's **put** this in writing so it's official.

or

> Let me jot **down** a grocery list so I don't forget.

To *put down* a pet means to euthanize it.

> My dog got sick and I had to **put** him **down**.

To *put down* for a nap usually means to put a baby in a crib for a nap.

> I **put** Alice **down** for a nap 20 minutes ago and she's still asleep.

It could be slang for "Do you understand what I'm saying?"

> Are you picking up what I'm **putting down**?

This one is also very uncommon.

Comment: Thanks. The agony was, not actually more about "putting down" but rather the verb "feature". I stopped completely there. Thank you.

Comment: +1. Just wanted to mention though that I think you left out one very common meaning of put down, which would be to disparage someone.

Answer (score 1):

This question is about a very ambiguous statement that is open to interpretation, but my reading of this, in context, is quite different from the other answer. I get something like this out of it:

> I don't want to focus on romantic love in my life, but stupid cupid is making me do it, anyway.

It's unusual to use the verb "feature" this way, but if I said something like "I don't feature exercise in my life," I would mean it was something I didn't do much, didn't like, or didn't want to focus on.

What is meant by "puttin' down" is even more problematic, but I don't think it's totally out of the ballpark to read it as some sort of force or coercion, sort of akin to "laying down the law."

Anyway, that doesn't invalidate the other answer. Ultimately, I don't think there is any really clear answer about what this means, unless Mandy Moore has one.

Comment: Thank you for your own answer. I am afraid I don't understand about the part "I don't feature exercise"....

Comment: Hm. To help you understand that, I would need to get a sense of what you understand about "feature" when it is used as a verb. Do you understand, for example: _This movie features a lot of gore_?

Comment: Would that mean "This" feature gives special attention to the scene full of blood? on the ground that gore means blood?

Comment: Sort of. It would mean that the movie probably has a lot of scenes with vivid depictions of violence. However, it further implies that the movie is treating gore as a positive or artistic thing, focusing on it, and treating it as a selling point of the movie. Does that help at all to understand what it might mean to "feature" exercise (or love) in your life? Like I say, though, this usage in the song is very strange, no matter how you look at it. Even as a native English speaker, I'm just making wild guesses.

Comment: **this usage in the song is very strange** O.K then, to non native speakers  it's gonna be Mount Everest size.

Comment: @KentaroTomono lol, all I can say is that I've decided I'll never be sure I understand it, so I'm just going to move on, and I certainly wouldn't blame you for doing the same! ;)

Comment: This is an American slang usage of "feature", meaning "approve of"; see [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=qX5aDwAAQBAJ&pg=RA13-PA1976&lpg=RA13-PA1976&dq=%22don%27t+feature%22+slang+verb&source=bl&ots=WhO0umU9pf&sig=7yBrqH1rOZQe5Fr8d88UPM6j56o&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwivxdb-95_bAhVfHTQIHUJdBvIQ6AEIQjAD#v=onepage&q=%22don't%20feature%22%20slang%20verb&f=false).

Answer (score 0):

The song is called Stupid Cupid.
It was written by Neil Sedaka around 1960-61.
He sang it, but it was made famous by and is one of the signature songs of Connie Francis from around the same time.

The line in question is actually 2 slang expressions popular specifically at that time.

Feature... meaning I don't appreciate or like something.
Putting Down... In this case, what you're doing, how you're acting.
I don't like/appreciate the way you're acting.
I don't like/appreciate what you're doing.

"Putting down" has other meanings, that came out at different times, such as to disparage... to put a person down.
It has other definitions that you can look up.

However in this specific lyric, she's saying I don't like or appreciate what you're doing.